# JQuery 1.6.1 and Checkbox Attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery 1.6.1 and found that

```
 $("#theChk').attr("checked", "");
```

OR

```
$("#theChk").prop("checked", false);
```

none of this are working .  Can some one find reason based on this http://blog.jquery.it/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/ ?

Do I have to change whole application for this change ??!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having `"` on the left side of selector and `'` on the right side of selector

and use .attr

```
$("#theChk").attr("checked", false);
```

to uncheck it, to check it use

```
$("#theChk").attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: Good catch, I missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#theChk").removeAttr("checked");`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
 $('#theChk').attr('checked', false);
```

checked takes a boolean not a string.  I'm not sure why your example that uses `prop` is not working.  From what I can see that looks fine.

Comment: As you can see i had it as false which surely is boolean.

Comment: No you didn't.  You have it as `""` which is an empty string.

Comment: No, as of jQuery 1.6 you should be using `prop` for things like this.

Answer (score -1):

If you're setting a value, use .prop and a non-quoted boolean:

```
$('#theChk').prop('checked', true)
```

If youre checking if it's checked, leave out the boolean:

```
if ($('#theChk').prop('checked'))
```

So it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Isn't he already doing the first example you gave of using `prop`?

Comment: I don't know what he's trying to accomplish. Is he checking or setting? And by checking I mean seeing if it is checked.

Comment: I know, I'm showing the difference between two things. I only repeat the setting part to contrast it with getting.